# Arabic and Hindi Data not Showing Correctly PHP

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I uploaded csv file using phpmyadmin, and it is correctly uploaded and data is displayed correctly as showing in the following image.

**Table Structure**

[image]

**Data in the Database**

[image]

But on browser it is showing like this, means unreadable just ????? Showing on the page.

[image]

Here is how i am getting data using php

```
function get_quran_surat(){
        $query ="select suraid,suraname from quran group by suraid,suraname";
        $result=$this->query($query);
        $this->setcharset();
        $rows=array();
        while($row=$this->fetch_array($result)){
            $rows[]=$row;
        }
        return $rows;   
}
```

Also add the `utf-8` in head section of the page.

[image]

**Edited Table Structre**

[image]

**Question**

How can i show readable data in the browsers ?

Comment: Your collation and HTML charset look good so it's probably your MySQL connection charset. See the **Data Access** section in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/279279/283366)

Comment: If that doesn't actually answer your question, let me know here in the comments

Comment: @Phil i changed charset to utf8mb4_general_ci but still wired characters are showing ?

Comment: Could you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67394550/edit) to include the relevant parts of your code? Show how you're setting the connection charset. Also show how you're displaying the data from `get_quran_surat()`

Comment: The connection charset needs to be made **before** you query. It's best done immediately after opening the connection. Also, `mysqli_set_charset()` takes **two** parameters

Comment: @Phil Adding the mysqli_set_charset showing the data correctly. Code edited in question